# Understanding Linked List with Python

Tags: python, linked-list

I am doing self study on Linked Lists with Python. I'm trying to grapple with trying to visualize the structure and concept of linked lists. Below is code from self study that is asking for me to add the missing code. Can some one please draw out or explain how I should picture this. I am familiar with regular python lists, dict, and other common data structures. But for example for the method my thought process is

```
if current:
    return current.value
else:
    return None
```

But this is incorrect. Am I checking that the constructor initialized a list and has a element variable current? Below is full code. Thank you.

```
"""The LinkedList code from before is provided below.
Add three functions to the LinkedList.
"get_position" returns the element at a certain position.
The "insert" function will add an element to a particular
spot in the list.
"delete" will delete the first element with that
particular value.
Then, use "Test Run" and "Submit" to run the test cases
at the bottom."""

class Element(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self, head=None):
        self.head = head

    def append(self, new_element):
        current = self.head
        if self.head:
            while current.next:
                current = current.next
            current.next = new_element
        else:
            self.head = new_element

    def get_position(self, position):
        """Get an element from a particular position.
        Assume the first position is "1".
        Return "None" if position is not in the list."""
        return None

    def insert(self, new_element, position):
        """Insert a new node at the given position.
        Assume the first position is "1".
        Inserting at position 3 means between
        the 2nd and 3rd elements."""
        pass


    def delete(self, value):
        """Delete the first node with a given value."""
        pass

# Test cases
# Set up some Elements
e1 = Element(1)
e2 = Element(2)
e3 = Element(3)
e4 = Element(4)

# Start setting up a LinkedList
ll = LinkedList(e1)
ll.append(e2)
ll.append(e3)

# Test get_position
# Should print 3
print ll.head.next.next.value
# Should also print 3
print ll.get_position(3).value

# Test insert
ll.insert(e4,3)
# Should print 4 now
print ll.get_position(3).value

# Test delete
ll.delete(1)
# Should print 2 now
print ll.get_position(1).value
# Should print 4 now
print ll.get_position(2).value
# Should print 3 now
print ll.get_position(3).value
```

Comment: I would suggest making a `print_list` function that prints out a set of linked list nodes like this: `1->2->3->4` so you can call this function whenever you like to help visualize the state of the list.

Answer (score 1):

> for the method my thought process is...

What method? `get_position`? `insert`? `delete`?

As @JacobIRR suggested, adding a way of printing your linked list can be helpful. Take a look:

```
class Element:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None


class LinkedList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def append(self, value):

        element = Element(value)

        if self.head is None:
            self.head = element
            return

        cursor = self.head
        while cursor.next is not None:
            cursor = cursor.next
        cursor.next = element

    def __str__(self):

        values = []

        cursor = self.head
        while cursor is not None:
            values.append(cursor.value)
            cursor = cursor.next
        return " -> ".join(values)


def main():

    linked_list = LinkedList()

    linked_list.append("Foo")
    linked_list.append("Bar")
    linked_list.append("Fizz")
    linked_list.append("Buzz")

    print(linked_list)

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
Foo -> Bar -> Fizz -> Buzz
```

Comment: What @user... has done here is add a type of "traverse" operation to `__repr__`, which is very helpful in many situations.  It is worth abstracting this into a separate method as you'll find you may use it again later.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do:

**Firstly**, try to visualize what will be happening while changing this state to that, or like- write the whole visualization on a paper or even in any online software to understand the changes.

**Lastly/Finally**, make sure that you know the core concept of linked-lists and do some tricky, bunch of different operation with it. Or, you may search on *Google* for a couple of resources.

Well, here is the solution I did for your problem:

> ```
> class Element(object):
>     def __init__(self, value):
>         self.value = value
>         self.next = None
>
> class LinkedList(object):
>     def __init__(self, head=None):
>         self.head = head
>
>     def append(self, new_element):
>         current = self.head
>         if self.head:
>             while current.next:
>                 current = current.next
>             current.next = new_element
>         else:
>             self.head = new_element
>
>     def get_position(self, position):
>         counter = 1
>         current = self.head
>         if position < 1:
>             return None
>         while current and counter <= position:
>             if counter == position:
>                 return current
>             current = current.next
>             counter += 1
>         return None
>
>     def insert(self, new_element, position):
>         counter = 1
>         current = self.head
>         if position > 1:
>             while current and counter < position:
>                 if counter == position - 1:
>                     new_element.next = current.next
>                     current.next = new_element
>                 current = current.next
>                 counter += 1
>         elif position == 1:
>             new_element.next = self.head
>             self.head = new_element
>
>     def delete(self, value):
>         current = self.head
>         previous = None
>         while current.value != value and current.next:
>             previous = current
>             current = current.next
>         if current.value == value:
>             if previous:
>                 previous.next = current.next
>             else:
>                 self.head = current.next
>
>
>
> # Test cases
> # Set up some Elements
> e1 = Element(1)
> e2 = Element(2)
> e3 = Element(3)
> e4 = Element(4)
>
> # Start setting up a LinkedList
> ll = LinkedList(e1)
> ll.append(e2)
> ll.append(e3)
>
> # Test get_position
> # Should print 3
> print(ll.head.next.next.value)
> # Should also print 3
> print(ll.get_position(3).value)
>
> # Test insert
> ll.insert(e4,3)
> # Should print 4 now
> print(ll.get_position(3).value)
>
> # Test delete
> ll.delete(1)
> # Should print 2 now
> print(ll.get_position(1).value)
> # Should print 4 now
> print(ll.get_position(2).value)
> # Should print 3 now
> print(ll.get_position(3).value)
> ```

Again, any further problem; take a paper, write the code and visualize what's happening.